How to get Cookie in Reactjs
How to get cookies from java backend in reactjs axios headers and I get this error: Set-Cookie malicious header failed to set   Here are my codes
const checkAuth = async () => {
    try {
      api
        .get("url", {
          headers: {
            "Set-Cookie": "user_info",
          },
        })

        .then((response) => {
          //what I write here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
      // Setting up user information

      // API javobi status kodini tekshirish
    } catch (error) {
      // If the error status code is 403, redirect to the login page
      if (error.response?.status === 403) {
        window.location = "/auth/login";
      } else {
        const errorMessage =
          error?.response?.message || "An unexpected error occurred";
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }
    }
  };

headers: {
"Set-Cookie": "user_info",
},
If I do, it should give me the user_info, but I have it
"Refused to set the secure header 'Set-Cookie' is causing this error"
